# Why can run Java program manually in a Docker image but not as an ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, java-11

I created an openjdk-11 alpine docker image and copied my jar into it. My Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM pwittchen/alpine-java11
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /opt/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app.jar"]
```

If I run:

```
docker run -it image
```

then

```
Error loading shared library libjli.so: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java)
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_Launch: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_PreprocessArg: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_ReportMessage: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_StringDup: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_MemFree: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_InitArgProcessing: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_AddArgsFromEnvVar: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_List_add: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/share/jdk-11/bin/java: JLI_List_new: symbol not found
```

But if:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh image
```

Then I can execute directly in the shell:

```
$ java -jar /opt/app.jar
```

And works.

**Why running as ENTRYPOINT makes the libjli.so library shadow and try relocating JLI*?**

Comment: Since I can not comment... There is problem with musl and jdk, You can notice that Alpine is dropped from tags for openjdk docker images https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/ You can try a different distro with libc

Comment: Is this really a problem with libc? Because I'm using openjdk no oracle-jdk and being able to run the program manually from shell makes me think this is not a problem of libraries but about permissions or environmental variables. No ideas?

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, I tested using the https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-glibc with the same result, what makes me think this is not really a problem related to absence of libc.

Comment: 3d party glibc is not a solution in some cases .. Try ubuntu/debian, or centos/rhel image for example

Comment: that is not really and option, all this exercise to make my app work on Java 11 was to reduce the docker image size using jlink to 50MB, if I use a sid or slim image I will end with more than 100MB. And then, it's better to stick with the old friend openjdk8-alpine image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in musl. When you execute directly from the shell musl is able to read the Library PATH but when you execute using CMD and/or ENTRYPOINT musl is not able to resolve the Library Path.

I was able to find this after reading and old issue already solved in openjdk8-alpine. Then this is a regression.

https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/77

To solve, first create a file **ld-musl-x86_64.pat** specifying where are the libraries required by musl. The file contents look like this:

```
/lib
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/share/jdk-11/lib/jli
```

The copy the file to the docker image in the build stage. My new Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM pwittchen/alpine-java11
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
#Copy the configuration file with the Library path!
COPY ld-musl-x86_64.path /etc/ld-musl-x86_64.pat
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /opt/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app.jar"]
```

Finally working.